# Are query string parameters in HTTPS visible in DNS resolvers?

Tags: domain-name-system, https, url

There was a case in a project I am working on, we had to send a JWT token as a Query parameter for another service. Due to security reasons one of my colleagues argued that the token would be visible and captured by DNS resolvers. Is this true?

Are there any other safety concerns one should make regarding sending a token visible in a query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS isn't concerned with the actual URL you're trying to reach, only the **domain name** (i.e. `www.example.com`). In other words, your computer/browser isn't going to tell the DNS server the entire URL. That's reserved for the actual web server (nginx, Apache, etc). Remember, there's other reasons to do DNS lookups that are not related to web sites.

> Are there any other safety concerns one should make regarding sending a token visible in a query string?

If the query string contains data that could modify records, you should consider a POST instead. Also, if the query string is human readable, it could easily be shared, and thus leak data that way.

```
https://www.example.com/page?username=mysecretusername
```

Comment: So, in this particula rcase, since it's a token with an expiration date, and doesn't modify any records, it shouldn't be the reason of any concerns right? It is, in top of it, used via HTTPs.

Comment: Sounds fine. I pass random tokens in the URL all the time